# How to modify Caffe network input for C++ API?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm trying to use the MINST Caffe example via the C++ API, but I'm having a bit of trouble working out how to restructure the network prototxt file I'll deploy after training. I've trained and tested the model with the original file ([lenet_train_test.prototxt](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt)), but when I want to deploy it and make predictions like in the [C++ and OpenCV example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp), I realise I have to modify the input section to make it similar to the [deploy.prototxt](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt) file they have.

Can I replace the information in the training and testing layers of the lenet_train_test.prototxt with this section of the deploy.prototxt file?

```
name: "CaffeNet"
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 10
  dim: 3
  dim: 227
  dim: 227
}
```

The images I'll be passing for classification to the network will be grayscale and 24*24 pixels, and I'll also want to scale it like was done with the MINST dataset, so could I modify the section to this?

```
name: "CaffeNet"
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 10
  dim: 1
  dim: 24
  dim: 24
}
transform_param {
scale: 0.00390625
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what the "`dim: 10`" is coming from though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to "convert" you *train_val* prototxt to a *deploy* one you remove the input data layers (reading your train/val data) and replacing them with the declaration

```
name: "CaffeNet"
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 10
  dim: 1
  dim: 24
  dim: 24
}
```

Note that the *deploy* prototxt does not have two phases for train and test only a single flavor.
Replacing the input data  layer with this declaration basically tells caffe that you are responsible of supplying the data, and the net should allocate space for inputs of this size.

Regarding scale: once you *deploy* your net, the net has no control over the inputs - it does not read the data for you as the input data layers in the *train_val* net. Therefore, you'll have to scale the input data yourself **before** feeding it to the network. You can use the [DataTransformer](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/data_transformer.hpp) class to help you transform your input blobs in the same way they were transformed during training.

Regarding the first `dim: 10`: every Blob (i.e., data/parameters storage unit) in caffe has 4 dimensions: batch-size, channels, height and width. This parameter actually means the net should allocate space for batches of 10 inputs at a time.
The "magic" number 10 comes from the way googlenet and other competitors in ILSVRC challenge used to classify images: they classified 10 crops from each image and averaged the outputs to produce better classification results.

Comment: If I already have my image as an OpenCV Mat, could I multiply each pixel by 0.00390625 to perform this scaling step without having to use the DataTransformer class?

Comment: @JackSimpson again, I'm not 100% sure, but it might be the case that you may do so.

Comment: @JackSimpson Hi , I'm wondering if you could solve this issue? Would you please share your experience with me ? I am running and getting the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I ended up multiplying each pixel when I used the model to make predictions.