# Error with Caffe C++ example with different deploy.prototxt file

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I [trained](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt) a model using the MNIST [example architecture](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt) (but on my own set of 3 image classes) and have been trying to integrate it into the [C++ example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp). I modified the MNIST architecture file to make it similar to the deploy.prototxt file for the [C++ example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt) ([replacing the train and test layers with the input layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208193/how-to-modify-caffe-network-input-for-c-api/32211796?noredirect=1#comment52319229_32211796)).

Unfortunately, when I run the C++ program it gives me the following error:

> F0827 14:57:28.427697 25511 insert_splits.cpp:35] Unknown bottom blob
>    'label' (layer 'accuracy', bottom index 1)

I tried to Google it and I think there's some difference between the layers in the files for the MNIST and C++ examples but can't work out what I can change to make this work.

Comment: Did you remove the accuracy and loss layers? You don't need them anymore in deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That was most of what I was missing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by [AbdulRahman AlHamali's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241193/error-with-caffe-c-example-with-different-deploy-prototxt-file#comment52364300_32241193) it seems like you left in your `deploy.prototxt` file the loss and accuracy layers that expects as inputs ("bottom"s) `"label"`.
Removing these loss layers from `deploy.prototxt` should solve the poroblem.

Note, that if you used `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` layer as a loss, you need to *replace* it with a `"Softmax"` layer to get class probabilities as the net outputs. `"Softmax"` layer takes only one `"bottom"` and does not require `bottom: "label"`.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: ok @Shai, thanks. I'm trying another thing right now and I'll definitely post another question and let you know. I'm deleting all the older comments now.