# Unable to proceed with training in Caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am training my own model on some MR images in Caffe. When I try to train the model, I get the following error:

> Unknown bottom blob 'label' (layer 'accuracy', bottom index 1)

I looked at a similar question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241193/error-with-caffe-c-example-with-different-deploy-prototxt-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241193/error-with-caffe-c-example-with-different-deploy-prototxt-file%20/%22here%22), The accepted answer for that question asked the OP to remove the `"Accuracy"` and loss layers from the `deploy.prototxt` file. I have done that also, and still the error persists. I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you have a layer with `bottom: "label"`, that is, a layer that expects as (one of its) inputs `"label"`. However, it seems like no layer in your model produces `"label"` as an output of that layer: no layer has `"label"` as one of its `"top"`s.

Please review your model's prototxt to find where `"label"` should come from, or alternatively, eliminate layers that requires `"label"` as an input.

Comment: Thank you. Your input helped me figure out the error.